# OSGeo Network Installer Download Error

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

[image: OSGeo Network installer download error]

I am having issue with completing download of components using the OSGeo4w 64bit installer. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it.
I am testing this in Windows 10 20H2 64bit machine, no proxy network.

After contunuing with 'No' option, then during installation another error message box shows as shown below.

[image]

Comment: do you have enough disk space? an intermittent internet connection?

Comment: Yes I do. I have over 300GB disk space. Internet is also connected and not intermittent rather continuous.

Comment: What happens if you click Yes to Try again? I was updating QGIS yesterday and it happened to me. Clicked Yes and all went well afterwards.

Comment: When clicking Yes it repeats the installation procedure which still results in the same error of 'Download Incomplete'. Like a loop.

Comment: as a workaround, individual components can be downloaded and installed on their own (i.e not with the OSGeo4 installer)

Comment: Thanks @JGH Let me try that.